# In If Else condition if any number taken then it will show error.how it will be done in AUTOIT

Tags: autoit

I just want to run a loop at autoit where if i take any kind of number then the code wont execute The code is below,

```
If  $Number($read, "")Then

;We have it, display the message.

MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "The following values were converted to a numeric value:" & @CRLF & _
        $Number)

Else
;Get Existing Data of edit
$read2 = GUICtrlRead($hEdit)
$text = $read2 & @CRLF & $read ;
```

Comment: Your snippet gives less information. You are using a function pointer to `$Number`, but we can't see, what this function does. I'm not sure what your code should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check if a value is a number, and execute the code if it's NOT. If so, use [`IsNumber()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsNumber.htm). For example:

```
$testVar = 1
If Not (IsNumber($testVar)) Then
    MsgBox(0, "Title", "This code will not execute as the variable's a number.")
Else
    MsgBox(0, "Title", "This code WILL execute since the variable is a number.")
EndIf

$testVar2 = "String"
If Not (IsNumber($testVar2)) Then
    MsgBox(0, "Title", "This code WILL execute since the variable is NOT a number.")
Else
    MsgBox(0, "Title", "This code will not execute as the variable's NOT a number.")
EndIf
```

If `$testVar` IS a number, but that number is in quotes, it will be recognized as a string instead and execute (as it's not a number).